# Read data from a .dat file and put them into an array in python

Tags: python, spyder

I have a .dat file with the following data:

```
16 32 0.0498392 -0.432943 3 0.435802
32 32 0.0629429 -0.396567 3 0.401531
```

etc.

I want to extract and put them into an array in python, using spyder. I have tried to just read and print, but even that simple code wouldn't go right.

Thank you

Comment: Can we see that code?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, this place is about solving problems, not about getting others to code for you. Please show the code that you tried, and we will be happy to try to find the issue.